# finder leak (?) while running my App in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

Hmmm ... and now for a completely different leak! I have noticed that when I run an App currently in development in the iPhone simulator, the Finder process creeps to 1+Gb of memory and chews up 1 core from my box.  I looked high and low in my app, and found nothing suspicious, whether with instruments or home grown monitoring facilities. The ONLY disk IO done by this App is to save a (small) .plist at 5 seconds interval or so.

Anyone noticed/fixed that ? If yes, would like to hear your solution.

MBP recent, 16 Gb memory, OSX 10.7.5 
Xcode 4.5
Simulator version 6, running iOS 6.0

this is a game app, cocos2d centric.

Comment: How does it behave on a device? That's what counts.

Comment: hahaha ... you're preaching to the choir ! Memory footprint is a rock on device(s), but i have not logged many play hours yet, so i cant tell whether it is affecting other system components. This is just a 'fly' that I would like to swat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behaviour has disapeared in EAP 2.0 version. So far Finder at 67 Mb memory, <2% cpu, stable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try profile it (command+I) and check for leaks.
Sometimes, we call system functions and THEY leak.